How can I stop Uber from changing my pickup location?
Uber routinely seems to be changing the pickup location on riders now, requiring them to walk to some different street, apparently one that is more convenient for the drivers. This is very disorienting for me, especially if I am in an unfamiliar or possibly dangerous place and do not want to figure out where I need to walk to.
How can I force Uber to use my requested pickup address and not try to change it?

Do you have specific examples? And do you mean at booking time or after you have booked? As far as I know they do it in locations like airport and train stations where there is a dedicated pick up location (simply because they are not allowed to pick you up elsewhere). But in my experience this is clearly done at booking time.

@jcaron They do it EVERYWHERE in anything remotely resembling an urban environment. Do you even use Uber? Just as an example, today I asked to be delivered to 320 Compass Circle in N. Kingstown RI and the pickup location I got was on Independence Drive which would have required me to walk a long block through a desolate industrial area. I mean WTH? Uber wants to walk through this industrial area instead of just picking me up where I want to be picked and I could not turn it off. You can "move" the pickup location, but I was unable to do that successfully to move it with my finger.

How did they respond when you contacted them?

@Berend Contacted who?

There are suggestions on Reddit Uber can force you to go to designated taxi pick-up points or other areas where waiting is permitted, but it's not clear if you're in an urban area with restrictions or not. Alternatively you can try and move your pickup location after the order is placed - can you do that? (BTW as for suggesting the OP contact Uber, good luck with that!)

I suppose you mean International Drive. Did the app correctly show your location? Sometimes it can take a little time for the phone to get an accurate position. Also you can click on the address and drag the map around to change the pick up location to the correct one if it didn’t get it right by itself. What kind of phone do you have?

Also you haven’t told us: is the alternate address shown before you order the ride, or after that? Also remember you can always contact the driver as soon as one is assigned to you.
